# How to convert specific ordinary list to nested list

Tags: python, list

**Background on the problem:**

Basically I'm making a "chatbot" and I want to feed it a lot of data from a text file. In this example, 0 means humans, and 1 means chatbot. The list always starts with the human talking and both the human and the robot can have multiples responses. Based on the list of possible responses I would like to generate a list of all possible conversations. I know this can be done using recursion but I just can't wrap my head around it :(
Preferably answer this in pseudo-code or python. However, I'm open to any programming language.

**Example:**

```
Given: [ [0, "Hello"], [0, "Good morning"], [1, "Beep bop Im a bot"], [1, "Hello, dear human"], [0, "Okay, what time is it?" ]
```

```
Output: [ 
["Hello", "Beep bop Im a bot", "Okay, what time is it?"],
["Hello", "Hello, dear human", "Okay, what time is it?"],
["Good morning", "Beep bop Im a bot", "Okay, what time is it?"],
["Good morning", "Hello, dear human", "Okay, what time is it?"],
]
```

Comment: Is it necessary recursively-nested list?

Comment: Look at Combinatoric iterators in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html)

Comment: @BoseongChoi   No not necessary, my main objective is to use a recursive function to write to a YAML file. I will try to edit the question if I can.

Comment: Why do you need 0 and 1? Wouldn't something like this be better```[ ["Hello", "Hi"], ["Hello human"], ["What time is it?"] ]```. Still inserting any path dialogue would be complicated once you get 100 reactions or more.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Please show us what did you done until now. So we can assist you to finish it.

Comment: @kederrac      No, as I said 0 is human, and 1 is chatbot. I also posted some further clarification above in the comments.

Comment: @Melon         I'm using 0 and 1 in order to know who is speaking (Human or chatbot). And given the list all possible talks it gives me all the possible dialogue the 2 can come up with.

Comment: @AhmedKhalf "All possible talks" means including shuffled order? like `["What time is it?", "Hello human", "Hi"]`. Can human or chatbot say more than one chat at once? like `["Hi", "What time is it?", "Hello human"]`. Can you explain more explicit rules?

Comment: can you provide an example more complex ? for example for: ' 00110101000111' ?

Comment: @tdelaney      The iterator is great however I'm looking at a solution involving recursion of functions. I haven't specified this but I'm saving the possible conversation in a YAML file one by one. This will allow me to not use a lot of memory.

Comment: @AhmedKhalf `itertools` may uses less memory than recursion. It depends on algorithm, though.

Comment: @kederrac      Sorry for the confusion guys I edited my question to provide a more correct and detailed view of my problem.

Comment: @AliNikneshan  Sorry Ali, don't have any code, however, you can look at the comments and the edited question for more guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for longest paths into a simple oriented graph like this:

```
"Hello" ------->\ /->"Beep bop Im a bot"->\
                 X                         X-->"Okay, what time is it?"
"Good morning"->/ \->"Hello, dear human"->/
```

So you are looking for alterning paths in:

```
given = [ [0, "Hello"], [0, "Good morning"], [1, "Beep bop Im a bot"], [1, "Hello, dear human"], [0, "Okay, what time is it?" ] ]
```

The recursive answer is natural here:

- if `given` is empty, you have only an empty path.
- if `given` is not empty, let `head, tail` be the first element of `given` and, resp., the remaining elements of `given`. You have three possibilities:

  1. if `tail` is empty, then the only path is `[head.sentence]`;
  2. else, if `head.speaker != first element tail.speaker`, then yield `[head.sentence] + path` foir every path in `tail`;
  3. else, if `head.speaker == first element tail.speaker`, then:
     a. yield the paths in `tail` (recursive call)
     b. remove the first element of `tail` and loop to 3. until you are in case 1. or 2.

Why does it works? (sketch of demonstration):

(I) You have: `given[0].speaker == path.speaker` for every `path` in `paths(given)`. Thats true if `given` has only one element. Else, you yield the path `head.sentence + <something> == given[0].sentence + <something>`, or you yield a `path` in `paths(tail)` where `tail[0].speaker == head.speaker == given[0].speaker`

- Rotation: You only yield directly an element in case 1. or 2., when `head.sentence` is followed by `paths(tail)` and the speaker of the first element of tail is different from the speker of `head`. Given the proposition (I), you are sure that a human sentence is always followed by a computer sentence and conversely.
- Completeness: that's true for empty paths, and since you try every possible start because you call `paths` on every element until there is a rotation.

In python:

```
given = [ [0, "Hello"], [0, "Good morning"], [1, "Beep bop Im a bot"], [1, "Hello, dear human"], [0, "Okay, what time is it?" ] ]

def paths(L):
    if L:
        head, *tail = L
        while tail and tail[0][0] == head[0]:
            yield from paths(tail)
            _, *tail = tail

        for path in paths(tail):
            yield [head[1]] + path
    else:
        yield []

print(list(paths(given)))
```

Output:

```
[['Good morning', 'Hello, dear human', 'Okay, what time is it?'], ['Good morning', 'Beep bop Im a bot', 'Okay, what time is it?'], ['Hello', 'Hello, dear human', 'Okay, what time is it?'], ['Hello', 'Beep bop Im a bot', 'Okay, what time is it?']]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's about using dictionaries? You can add list of keys (human sentences) and their values (robot responses). I suppose that dividing sentences into categories is necessary in order to get resonable conversation.

For example

```
import random
from datetime import date

human_greetings = ['hi', 'hello']
robot_greetings = ['hello human', 'hi buddy']
talk = dict()

talk['time'] = ['It is...']
talk['date'] = [('Today is ' + str(date.today()))]


for greeting in human_greetings:
    talk[greeting] = robot_greetings

while True:
    human = str(input())
    robot = random.choice(talk[human])
    print(robot)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, however, I'm making a chatbot with millions of pairs that need to be trained using machine learning. I should have been more clear in the question... but basically I'm converting this list to a Yaml file for training and I'm not going to use the list for raw prediction. I suggest you read the comments and the edited question for an example of what I'm trying to achieve.